# Open p:dialog when asynchronous task is completed

Tags: jsf, asynchronous, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

I need a technique in which I can call java method for retrieving information from `DB` and displaying message in dialog box and by pressing "Next" button, if have any next message it will appear. That java method calls automatically after a specific time, says first time when user logged-in and then after ever 3 min. This I want in JSF & PrimeFaces.

I used `ScheduleExecutarService` for scheduling and my run method as below

```
public void run() {
  try {
       System.out.println("beep");
       notificationList = retrieveNotificationsFromDB(userId, groupCode, functionCode, chooseNotificationType());

       if(notificationList != null && !notificationList.isEmpty()){                                 
            showPopup();
       }
    } catch(Exception e) {
          LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
     }
}

public void showPopup() {
    if (notificationList != null && !notificationList.isEmpty()) {
        setNotificatiomMessage(notificationList.get(0).getMessage());
        notificationList.remove(0);
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dialogVar').show()");
    }
}
```

**In `showPopup()` I'm not able to get the object of `RequestContext`**

Other Way I tried `<p:poll>` tag, I read that about the tag is there is a problem for stopping it.

Please guide me what I should use.

Answer (score 1):

> In showPopup() I'm not able to get the object of RequestContext

Because there is no active HTTP request (from the client to the server) which is handled at this point.

**Solution:**

Let the Scheduler fire a CDI event and catch this event with a CDI observer in your client bean.

Now you have to options: Either let the JSF view poll your client bean to ask for new messages, or you create a socket, over which the client bean may inform the JSF view about new messages. You are able to handle the incoming message on your JSF view via JavaScript and do with it whatever you want.

For a very basic example for sockets, see here: 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/counter.xhtml

See also:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhic.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the simple solution with these 2 line of code

```
<p:poll id="initNotificationAlert" interval="1" oncomplete="PF('initNotificationVar').stop()"  listener="#{notificationView.retrieveAlertNotification()}" widgetVar="initNotificationVar"></p:poll>
<p:poll id="notificationAlert" autoStart="false" interval="180"  listener="#{notificationView.retrieveAlertNotification()}" widgetVar="notificationVar"></p:poll>
```

first `<p:pol>` for initial message and second for `<p:pol>` for rest. 
if any better solution of improvement need in this solution improve it.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can open dialog manually like this:

**Scheduler**
There are many schdulers like [Quartz](http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/integrating-quartz-scheduler-java-web-application/) or for [WebApplication](http://www.onjava.com/2006/02/29/job-scheduling-in-web-application.html)

**Dialog**

```
public String showDialog(String dialogName){
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        options.put("modal", true);
        options.put("closable", true);
        options.put("draggable", true);
        options.put("resizable", true);
        options.put("contentHeight", 386);
        options.put("contentWidth", 1266);

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog(dialogName, options, null);

        return "";
    }
```

While dialogName is that `.xhtml` page you are trying to show. You just need a schedular to call this method and dialog will appears.

Comment: Thanks....... but from where should I call this method?? from run() method?? If yes, are you sure will I not get null from `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()`? Because I was getting null from run method